# ASP.NET MVC: Accessing binded model in controller without using a form AND Ajax

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following scenario:

```
@model IEnumerable<UI.Models.Customer>

@grid.GetHtml(
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(
        format: @<text>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAct", ???)
        </text>
    ),
    grid.Column(
        format: @<text>
            @Html.TextBox("Name", (string)item.Name)
        </text>
        )
    )
)
```

model is just a List consisting of 3 Customer's (Customer is a dummy class with only 2 properties, i.e. ID and Name)

Now, i want to be able to capture in the controller action "EditAct "the Customer, which the user want's to edit. Those were the things, that i desperately tried without success:

---

1) I tried to fill in ??? with a

```
new {customer: item}
```

and to capture it in controller this way:

```
public ActionResult SampleFormParams(Customer customer) {...}
```

This approach does not work, because HTML anchor links uses GET and we can't send an object with GET.

---

2) It tried to fill in ??? with a

```
new {customer: jsSerializer.Serialize(item)}
```

and to capture it in controller this way:

```
public ActionResult SampleFormParams(String customer) { //deserialize(customer) }
```

This also does not work, because "item" is not a Customer object, but it is a WebGridRow object.

---

3) It tried to fill in ??? with a

```
new {customer: item.ID}
```

and to capture it in controller this way:

```
public ActionResult SampleFormParams(int id) { ... }
```

I wanted to know if it would be possible to access the whole IEnumerable model, so that i can find the specified customer in the model using the given id ?

---

So the question is, is there any way, that i can access model directly just with an anchor i.e. ActionLink 
- without using a form> AND without using Ajax ?

I also checked the Custom Model Binder, but it is also based on a form>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating edit link your way manually use a out of the box grid extension called getselectlink. here is an sample:

```
grid.Column(
            header:"", 
            format:@<text>@item.GetSelectLink("Edit")</text>
            ),
```